# Can we rotate a text in \psmatrix?(different)

Tags: pstricks, psmatrix

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathptmx}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node} % required package
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
\psmatrix[,colsep=1.5cm]
              & [mnode=circle] X \\
[mnode=oval] ABCD &  \psframebox[framearc=.3]{E}
\endpsmatrix
\psset{nodesep=3pt,nrot=:U}
\ncline{1,2}{2,1}
\nbput{abcd}
\ncline{<-}{1,2}{2,2}
\ncput*{ch}
\ncline[linestyle=dotted]{2,1}{2,2}
\nbput{dcba}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

1. How to `[mnode=circle] X`,`[mnode=oval] ABCD`,`\psframebox[framearc=.3]{E}` is rotated 45 degree?
2. How to ensure that the whole figure is rotated by 90 degree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the rotated figure, there is the `\rotateleft` command, but it doesn't turn the node connection labels (or I do not know how to do it). So I redesigned the figure, but I'm not sure it's exactly what you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathptmx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node} % required package
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\psmatrix[,colsep=1.5cm]
 [mnode=circle] \rotateleft{X} & \psframebox[framearc=.3]{\rotateleft{E}} \\
 & [mnode=oval] \rotateleft{ABCD}
\endpsmatrix
\psset{nodesep=3pt,nrot=:U}
\ncline{1,1}{2,2}
\nbput{abcd}
\ncline{<-}{1,1}{1,2}
\ncput*{c\smash[t]{h}}
\ncline[linestyle=dotted]{1,2}{2,2}
\naput{dcba}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to them are rotated 45 degree? " I think to rotate it by 90, we can rotate in the "includegraphic[angle=90,...] ". My opinion is true?

Comment: You can rotate by whatever angle you want if you compile the pstricks image as `standalone` and include & rotate the resulting .pdf. You also can rotate from within pstricks, but there a problem with the node connection labels. as you can in my code, even to turn by 90degrees irequires a special treatment of these labels.